# How to safely switch from 64bit to 32bit Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-7-x64

I have installed 64-bit Python on Windows 7 and used it for a while. Now I need to switch to 32-bit Python because some libraries require 32-bit one. Can I do this easily, while preserving all previously installed libraries and settings?

Comment: You can find unofficial Windows x64 binaries for most packages [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtualenv to maintain environments that use distinct Python versions.

More directly to your question of keeping the same install-base, the answer is generally "no", you cannot keep the same installs. Some packages are obtained for a specific Python-version/OS/hardware combination (e.g. mypackagePy27Win64.exe) and such packages will have placed 64-bit-specific DLLs on your filesystem. Using virtualenv will let you isolate your new x32 work environment from your existing x64 work environment.